# Weird value bug onChange in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I ran into a weird bug for an autocomplete form. 
I've added a onChange function to the form which takes can access two args, the "event" and the "value".

the function looks like this:

```
handleChange(event, value){
      const the_new_state = event.target.id.split("-");

      console.log(the_new_state[0], value);
      this.setState({
        [the_new_state[0]]: value,
      });

};
```

**The following gets logged to the console: 



"selectOption"

["value1"]





If I add an extra option (multiple values):



"selectOption"

["value1", "value2"]**


This runs as expected, but it gets weird when I take a look at this.state.selectOption.
At the first run this.state.selectOption is set to an empty array. On the second run this.state.selectOption is set to **["value1"] instead of ["value1", "value2"]**.

Does anyone know what causes this bug?

Extra info regarding to line 2 of the function: 
Let's say the default id of the element is "myOption". To make the id unique to each selected option , the id changes to "myOption-option-n", where n is the nth option in the list of options.

Comment: Where did you "take a look at this.state.selectOption"?

Comment: After the setState with console.log(this.state), but it's not shown in the function above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quote from React docs says:

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on **this.state** to reflect the new value immediately after calling **setState**. Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state.

Also, you have a callback function in **setState**, so you can do something like this

```
this.setState({ [the_new_state[0]]: value }, () => {
     // Or do whatever you want, the state should already be updated at this moment
     console.log(this.state); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks but somehow if I run the setState inside an if statement (if true) and i console.log the state inside and outside the if statement I get one correct state and one incorrect state. One is updated while the other one isn't. Is this a bug or is this just how setState works? (The function is not waiting for the state to be updated and prints the state before it's updated?)

Comment: You can think that **setState** just needs some time to really update the state. In other words, the changes are not instantaneous, they require some time. Such operations are called *asynchronous*. You'll never know how much time it requires to update the state, so you may or may not receive a correct answer depending on your luck...  If you want to rely on the previous state you can pass an updater function as a first argument. Details can be found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do